# What is the ideal way to populate a sidebar with Dynamic Data?

Tags: php, codeigniter, sidebar

I require a help for a sidebar. I checked some of the solutions here but could not figure out how to resolve it. Hence this post.

The sidebar lists all the available categories of something. This data is pulled from category table in mysql. Scenario is such that I need to dislay this sidebar in all pages. I have a view for sidebar. What I am doing right now is that I created a custom core controller, MY_Controller by extending the CI_Controller. I have a function called get_all_categories in My_Controller. Then in the index function of all other page controllers, I have this;

```
$categories = $this->get_all_categories();
$this->load->view('template/header');
$this->load->view('template/sidebar', $categories);
$this->load->view('home/index');
$this->load->view('template/footer');
```

I am not an expert in CI. Just learning. So just wanted to know if this is the right way to do it. Please advise...

Comment: you can display your side bar in the other page. just call it again if you want to display it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing is wrong with your approach however it is more common to move the `get_all_categories` function into a model, autoloading it, and then you could just do `$this->somemodel->get_all_categories()` you could even make a convenience function so you don't have to repeat the header and footer like so:

Model:

```
function template($main_view, $data = array()) {
    $categories = $this->get_all_categories();
    $this->load->view('template/header');
    $this->load->view('template/sidebar', $categories);
    $this->load->view($main_view, $data);
    $this->load->view('template/footer');
}
```

Comment: Dear Alex, Thankyou for the response and I will do as you advised. The idea of funtion found so convincing and easy. Thanks for that too. One small question though. Where do I put this function? Under 'Application/Library/my_library.php' and then add it to autoload?

Comment: OK... Thanks a lot Alex.... Resolved it. Added the function to the My_Controller and now I can call it $this->template("home/index", $data)

Comment: Yea like is said that's one place to put it but it's more common in a model or even, yes, a model. Ci has pretty good docs on how to create and autoload one. If this answer helped you please mark as accepted